# Automatically receive OTP and Verify the OTP, UI is not Updating

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to Implement Auto **otp** verify for my Ionic 4 App for Android. I was tried below code, I am able to receive the message but UI Input Filed is not updating the received **OTP**

**app.component.ts**

```
      constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public platform:Platform,
    public androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions,
    public http:Http,
  public navCtrl:NavController,
  public navParams: NavParams) {
    document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', function(e){
      var sms = e.data;

     console.log("received sms "+JSON.stringify( sms ) );

     if(sms.address=='HP-611773') //look for your message address
     {
       this.otp=sms.body.substr(0,4);

      this.verify_otp();
     }
    });

      }


 verifyOTP()
    {
      console.log("verify otp");

    }
```

I am able to see the alert with **OTP** but My Below UI is not Updating.

**app.component.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-button size="small" (click)="goBackToFirstTimeLogin()">Back</ion-button>
    <ion-title>verifyOTP</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Enter OTP</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="otp"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button (click)="verifyOTP()">Verify</button>
  <ion-button size="small" (click)="setPassword()">SetUp Password</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

`

`[(ngModel)]="otp"` value is not updating.

And I am Getting Below Error:

[Error Getting Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcGV0.png)

I follow below GitHub Link :

**https://github.com/bharathirajatut/ionic3/tree/master/SMSOTPVerificationAutomate**

Could you please help me someone, Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: Alert you have kept is generated..Right?

Comment: Yes, whatever I  received the message @Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I read lot of documents, I got the solution like, the code was not angular code, the code is non-angular, so angular don't know to update the view, so UI is not updating.

so non-angular code can update using the `Zone.js`

below code, I used for update my code :

```
 this.zone.run(() => {
          this.otp = sms.body.substr(20, 4);
          this.stopSMS();
        });
```

**below entire code :**

```
 document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', function(e){
      var sms = e.data;

     console.log("received sms "+JSON.stringify( sms ) );

     if(sms.address=='HP-611773') //look for your message address
     {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.otp = sms.body.substr(20, 4);
          this.verifyOTP();
        });
     }
    });
```

Now UI is updating very well.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in ionViewCanEnter(), so that it gets updated eachtime the view loads

Comment: Could you please let me know where  I call that method, Just I was edited my post could you please look into once and try to help me please. Thanks in advance !!!